# JavaScript not executing properly with Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've got the majority of it to work, but can't get my head around dynamically getting an ID of an element, and using that to input to a text box, which will be evaluated with eval()

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
        <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="outputBox">
            <div id="buttons">
                <button type="button" id="1" class="number">1</button>
                <button type="button" id="2" class="number">2</button>
                <button type="button" id="3" class="number">3</button>
                <button type="button" id="4" class="number">4</button>
                <button type="button" id="5" class="number">5</button>
                <button type="button" id="6" class="number">6</button>
                <button type="button" id="7" class="number">7</button>
                <button type="button" id="8" class="number">8</button>
                <button type="button" id="9" class="number">9</button>
                <button type="button" id="0" class="number">0</button>
                <button type="button" class="resize" id="reset">Clear</button>
            </div>
            <div id="operatordiv">
                <button type="button" id="+" class="operators">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="-" class="operators">-</button>
                <button type="button" id="*" class="operators">*</button>
                <button type="button" id="/" class="operators">/</button>
                <button type="button" id="calculate" class="operators">=</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(){
        print = document.getElementById(id).id;
        var text = document.getElementById("outputBox").value;
        document.getElementById("outputBox").value = text + print;
    });

    document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener('click', function(){
        var str = document.getElementById("outputBox").value;
        var n = eval(str);
        document.getElementById("outputBox").value = n;
    });

    document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("outputBox").value = "";
    });
});
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Calculator",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "description": "testcalc",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```

When I use OnClick attributes, everything works, and the JavaScript would get the ID and use that to know what to put in the textbox to be used by eval().
When I wrap them into the DOMContentLoaded event listener, it doesn't.

Comment: any error from javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it the problem is in how you're adding event listeners to your buttons. To access the id of the DOM element that triggers your anonymous function you can use the `this` keyword as such

```
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(){
    var print = this.id;
    var text = document.getElementById("outputBox").value;
    document.getElementById("outputBox").value = text + print;
});
```

Then you just need to attach an event listener to each button. I quickly put this together to accomplish that here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeDxe/

Of course creating anonymous functions in a loop isn't great, but neither is `eval`ing the contents of a user editable input field.

Comment: Apparently you aren't supposed to comment saying thanks on stackoverflow, but I have to say it. I knew which direction to go, but not how to get there. Thanks a lot!